# Why cant I connect to a Sql CE database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-ce, ssms

I have visual studio 2010. And sql management studio 2008. I have installed all the tools for Sql CE and I have created a new CE database using visual studio (by clicking the blue 'configure data source' hyperlink).

I have the following code on my .net 4.o page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace EasyMediaServer
{
    public partial class TestCeConnection : EMSPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Dropbox\Software Development\EMS\data\EMS.sdf");
            SqlCeCommand myCommand = new SqlCeCommand("Select * from tbl_media");
            myCommand.Connection = conn;

            conn.Open();

            SqlCeDataReader myReader =  myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            conn.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact
>   corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8482. Install the
>   correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for
>   more details.

What is going on? That article refers to CE 3.5...

Comment: This thread on the MSDN Forums might help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/d58b4b67-94a8-4478-b51f-c08f2f39ff43/

Comment: For starters I wouldn't be using Dropbox to host the data file. You're asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this blog post would be useful: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/07/getting-started-with-sql-server-compact.html